# React-Leaflet sticky Marker at the center of map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to create a Marker that always shows the centre of the map using React-Leaflet.

I managed to reference the map's central Lat Lng from `map.getCenter()` function, but when I applied to the position attribute on a Marker, nothing shows.

Here's the snippet of codes that I currently have.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
..

//mapping libraries & resources
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, LayersControl, Marker, useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import L from 'leaflet';
const { BaseLayer, Overlay } = LayersControl;

let crosshairIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/crosshair.png',
    iconSize:     [30, 30], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [10, 10], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
});


const { Content } = Layout;

const Home = (props) => {

    const [ position, setPosition] = useState([4.0112129, 108.1733503]);
    const [ zooms, setZooms ] = useState(6.4);
    const [ map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const [ centreMap, setCentreMap ] = useState(null);
    const [ crosshair, setCrosshair ] = useState(null);
    const [ altitude, setAltitude ] = useState(null);
   

    const DisplayMapHUD = ({map}) => {
        const [newPosition, setNewPosition] = useState(() => map.getCenter());

        const onMove = useCallback(() => {
            setNewPosition(map.getCenter())
            setCrosshair(map.getCenter())
        },[map])

        useEffect(() => {
            map.on('move', onMove);
            return () => {
                map.off('move', onMove);
            }
        },[map, onMove])

        return (
            <Row style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex:100, top:60, width: '500px', left: 0, right: 0, marginLeft:'auto', marginRight:'auto', paddingTop:5, paddingLeft:15, paddingBottom:5, paddingRight:15, color:'#000', height: 120, fontFamily:'Bebas Neue'}}>
                <Col flex='auto'>
                    <Row>
                        <span style={{letterSpacing: 3}}>MAP CENTRE</span>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Space direction="vertical" size={0}>
                            <span style={{ fontSize:'3em' }}>{newPosition != null ? newPosition.lat.toFixed(4) : 4.0112 }<span style={{ fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: '0.4em'}} >N</span></span>
                            <span>latitude</span>
                        </Space>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
                <Col flex='auto'>
                    <Row>
                        <span style={{letterSpacing: 3, visibility: 'hidden'}}>MAP CENTRE</span>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Space direction="vertical" size={0}>
                            <span style={{ fontSize:'3em' }}>{newPosition != null  ? newPosition.lng.toFixed(4) : 108.1733 }<span style={{ fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: '0.4em'}} >E</span></span>
                            <span>longitude</span>
                        </Space>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }

    const handleMapReady = (e) => {
        setCrosshair(e.target._lastCenter);
    }

    const leMap = useMemo(
        () => (
            <MapContainer ref={setMap} whenReady={handleMapReady} center={position} zoom={zooms} style={{ zIndex: 1, width:'calc(100vw - 80px)', height:'calc(100vh - 40px)' }}>
                <LayersControl>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution={`&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors`}
                        url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png" />
                        <Overlay checked name='Centre Crosshair'>
                        { crosshair ? <Marker position={crosshair} icon={crosshairIcon}></Marker> : null }
                        </Overlay>
                </LayersControl>
                <MouseCoords/>
            </MapContainer>
        ),[],
    )
    
    return (
        <Layout style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 40px)', backgroundColor: 'grey'}}>
            <Content>
                {map ? <DisplayMapHUD map={map} /> : null}
                {leMap}
            </Content>
        </Layout>
    )
} 
export default Home;
```

I couldn't make the `crosshair` icon Marker appear on the map, even though I've passed the centre of the map's LatLng into its `position` attribute.

Comment: Whats the purpose of this?  Why not use a non-leaflet element that lays completely on top of the `MapContainer`, instead of a map element that would constantly be lagging to catch up with the map center as the user pans / zooms?

Comment: @SethLutske, you've pointed out a very valid question. I ended up creating a new div with absolute positioning, and placed it at the dead centre of the map container. No lagging whatsoever! Thanks for the idea mate!